# Separating all values before "\" in python - EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

I have a column named "path" in a dataframe with values that look like this:

| ind | path |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | row\ nime\ Program one |
| 1 | space\ Lib \ Books \ The Final count down |

I want to be able to take the Path column, and select only the last word after the forward slash.
**ie**
*row\ nime\ Program one*  would be just *Program one*

Every code I write gives me EOL while scanning string literal.
take for instance

`df[Final path]= df["Path"].split("\")`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `df[Final path]= df["Path"].split("\\")`
[read more about it](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your `\`

```
s ='row\ nime\ Program one'
print(s.split('\\')[-1]) # --> Program one
```